# Social Studio Radian 6 Intregration with salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, social-content, social, radian6

I am using Social Studio to analyse the social data of FB and Twitter.

How can I integrate it with Salesforce so I can create a case in Salesforce for the posts and tweets?

Comment: You're gonna have to be more specific if you'd like this community to pitch in and help you.  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable Social Customer Service in Salesforce and connect the Radian 6 instance.

In Salesforce you [enable Social Customer](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=social_customer_service_setup.htm&type=0&language=en_US) service from the setup menu, then tick to enable Social Customer service. After that link the social accounts by entering the details.

Then you need to setup the [Social Action Interface](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=social_customer_service_custom_pub.htm&type=0&language=en_US) adding the quick actions to the case feed layout.

If required you can [customise the Apex class](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=social_customer_service_apexclass.htm&type=0&language=en_US) used for social post handling to give different behaviour than the default creation of a Social Persona and a Person Account.

Look at the full [Implementation Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/social_customer_service_impl_guide.pdf) for complete details.